# Save Messenger User Id to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to store all users ID of users clicking on a button of my Messenger Bot. I'm not really familiar with Javascript and MongoDB. I tried this but it seems it's not working:

-Index.js:

```
// DB
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
var User = require("./models/user");
```

-Model models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

-Index.Js to save the User ids using a payload:

```
if (text === '{"payload":"SUB_YES_PAYLOAD"}') {
                User.insert({ _id: event.sender.id })
        sendTextMessage(sender, "Merci pour votre inscription ! Voici les derniers articles publiés :", token)
                sendGenericMessage(sender)
        continue
      }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `User.create` instead of `User.insert`

Comment: Damn it, that was so easy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation, you need create the model like this:

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String
});
```

and create new instance like this (I modify with you details):

```
var user = new User.create({ id: event.sender.id' });
```

Read more: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

Comment: One must call `user.save()` in order to persist it into database.

Comment: or `user.create()`, it's come directly from model.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two easy ways to do so.

### First

```
User.create(data).then(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

### Second

```
var userInstance = new User(data);
userInstance.save().then(function(user){
  console.log(user);
});
```

mongoose would be fun if used with [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

`mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`
View [this documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for more.